# How to check if current time is between the time stored in Array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to check if my current time lies between any of Switch-1 or Switch-2 or Switch-3.
I tried in for-loop and matched conditions but somehow it is not working, I am not sure if it is due to string comparison.

Example :

1. If current time is 23-09-2020 7:45 then want to print **23-09-2020 Switch-1**
2. If current time is 23-09-2020 18:40 then want to print **23-09-2020 Switch-2**
3. If my current time is 24-09-2020 03:00 then want to print **23-09-2020 Switch-3** (current Date minus 1 Day)

i.e. Special case of time between 00:00 to 05:00 as date is changed to 24th Sep, I want current Date minus 1 Day i.e. 23rd Sep.

```js
var Data;
var m = moment().format('HH:mm')
console.log(m)
var Time = [

  {
    "switchName": 'switch 3',
    "start": '22:00',
    "end": '05:00'
  },
{
    "switchName": 'switch 1',
    "start": '05:00',
    "end": '15:00',
  },
   {
    "switchName": 'switch 2',
    "start": '15:00',
    "end": '22:00',
  },
  
]

    for (let i = 0; i < Time.length; i++) {
        const start = Time[i].start;
        const end = Time[i].end;
        if (start > end) {
            if (m <= start || m >= end) {                           
                data = {
                    currentdate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                    currentswitch: Time[i].switchName
                }

                console.log(data);
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (m >= start && m <= end) {
                data = { currentdate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'), currentswitch: Time[i].switchName }
                
                console.log(data);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Any help in this highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If `start > end` (i.e. the case of "switch 3"), your test is incorrect: `(m <= start || m >= end)`. It should be: `if (m >= start || m <= end)` (meaning 22-23 or 0-5).

You also wrote: *"If my current time is 03:00 then want to print 23-09-2020 Switch-3 (current Date minus 1)"*. There are two problems here:

- You said you want the date in DD-MM-YYYY format but you are using `format('YYYY-MM-DD')`. You'll have to decide what you want and change the format accordingly.
- You said you want "current Date minus 1" but it's not clear what "minus 1" means. Minus one second? Minute? Hour? Day? Month? Year? Assuming you mean "minus 1 day", you can use `moment().subtract(1, "days")` to subtract 1 day before formatting, so your final code would be:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < Time.length; i++) {
        const start = Time[i].start;
        const end = Time[i].end;
        if (start > end) {
                if (m <= start || m >= end) {                           
                        data = {
                                // Subtract 1 day:
                                currentdate: moment().subtract(1, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                                currentswitch: Time[i].switchName
                        }

                        console.log(data);
                        break;
                }
        }
        else {
                if (m >= start && m <= end) {
                        data = { currentdate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'), currentswitch: Time[i].switchName }

                        console.log(data);
                        break;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to subtract 1 day, this is because when current time is 24:00, day is changed to 24th Sep. So Switch-3 has two cases i.e. when current time between 22:00 to 24:00 I need date as 23-Sep, I need if current time is b/w 24:00 to 05:00 I want day as 23rd Sep. (24th Sep minus 1 day).

Comment: The above code doesn't work as it doesn't matches with any condition.

Comment: @GunjanAnshul Please provide an example of a condition where my code does not work.